# Deactivate lectins in beans by baking

Tags: biochemistry, food-chemistry

Having dried uncooked beans,
I read that the lectins can be deactivated by boiling and soaking for a while. What I could not find any information on is if dry baking beans would eventually deactivate the lectins too.

Does dry baking work to deactivate the lectins and if, how long at what temperature?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128293/discussion-on-question-by-alex-deactivate-lectins-in-beans-by-baking).

Answer (score 2):

Previous studies on the effect of "dry heating" (baking in an oven) on the hemagglutinating activity of legume lectin (a proxy for or direct cause of toxicity) from  [*P. vulgaris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaseolus_vulgaris) suggest that this is not a good way to suppress toxicity. Citing Ref. 1:

> Dry heating had little effect on hemagglutinating activity of certain
> varieties of P. vulgaris, and some activity was still detectable after several
> hours of heating (DeMuelenaere, 1964). Heintze (1950) found dry heating or
> high frequency treatment ineffective for the cooking of beans. However, the
> heating of soaked beans was fully effective. Too much heating reduces the
> growth induced by bean diets, probably due to the impairment of the nutritive
> value of the proteins (Kakade and Evans, 1965).

The precise answer probably depends on the identity of the bean.

*References*

1. Jaffe, W.G., Seidi, D.S., Toxicology of Plant Lectins, Ch. 11 in: Handbook of Natural Toxins, Vol. 7: Food Poisoning. Tu, A.T. (Ed.), Marcel Dekker (1992), ISBN  0824786521.